# Create a complex multidimensional array depending on input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I want to prepare and save an multidimensional array to send it via ajax. I have this HTML for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="itArray" value="id,1,name,Alex,gender,male" />
<input type="checkbox"  class="itArray" value="id,2,name,Max,gender,male" />
```

I want to achieve that every comma (`,`) seperates `key:value` pairs in a multidimensional array AND depending on the amount of commas it should create an array (e.g.: `5 commas = 3 key:value pairs` like in this example).

The array from this HTML example should look like this then:

[image]

(Sorry if I'm putting wrong brackets, I just want to demonstrate what I want to achieve and I don't know the correct syntax)

That is what I have done so far:

```
var itemsArray;
$('.itArray').each(function(key, value) {
    console.log(itemsArray);
    val = $(value).val();
    console.log("val " + val);
    var ar = val.split(',');
    var itemsArray = { // new each loop here with i % 2 ?  }

        // I don't know how to proceed here

    }
});
```

I guess I have to use `i % 2` to seperate each key:value pairs? But I don't know how to do that exactly in this specific case. I appreciate any help.

Edit: Added Image to show how I want it to look like. Sorry,  had to hide sensible data.

Comment: probably, you meant each item to be in this structure `{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Alex",
    "gender": "male"
  }`, right?

Comment: There is no such data format in js. If you are using php try `json_encode` on your data and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop each `input` with `each` loop and add to object with help of `reduce()`. Also there are no multidimensional arrays in js but you can use objects instead.

```js
var result = {}
$('.itArray').each(function(i) {
  var num = 0
  var val = $(this).val().split(',');
  result[i] = val.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
    if (i % 2) r[num++] = {[val[i - 1]]: e}
    return r;
  }, {})
})

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="itArray" value="id,1,name,Alex,gender,male" />
<input type="checkbox" class="itArray" value="id,2,name,Max,gender,male" />
```

Comment: Hey, can you please take a look at my question again and at my image? I used your code but there are too much arrays. I hope you understand it by the image I showed?

Comment: You can get data like this instead https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1044/ or just array of objects https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1045/ but there is no `[key => value]` in js it must be `{key: value}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var data = {items: []};
$(".itArray").each(function(key, item) {
    var i = 0;
    var d = item.value.split(",").reduce(function(memo, current, index, arr) {
        index % 2 === 0 ? memo.push({}) : memo[i++][arr[index-1]] = current;
        return memo;
    },[]);
    data.items.push(d);
});

console.log(data);
```

```js
var data = {items: []};
$(".itArray").each(function(key, item) {
    var i = 0;
    var d = item.value.split(",").reduce(function(memo, current, index, arr) {
        index % 2 === 0 ? memo.push({}) : memo[i++][arr[index-1]] = current;
        return memo;
    },[]);
    data.items.push(d);
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="itArray" value="id,1,name,Alex,gender,male" />
<input type="checkbox"  class="itArray" value="id,2,name,Max,gender,male" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get key values of `checked` checkbox with pure JavaScript.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.itArray:checked');

var kvArray = [];
elements
  .forEach(el => {
    var kvs = el.value.split(',');
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < kvs.length; i += 2)
      result.push({
        [kvs[i]]: kvs[i + 1]
      });
    kvArray.push(result);
  });

console.log(JSON.stringify(kvArray, 0, 4));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="itArray" value="id,1,name,Alex,gender,male" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="itArray" value="id,2,name,Max,gender,male" />
<input type="checkbox" class="itArray" value="id,3,name,Vaia,gender,female" checked/>
```